# Committing array to Vuex store mutation

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Store file:

```
state: {
    ...
    cases: [],
    ...

mutations: {
    setCases(state, items) {
        // items contains only the first object in the array
    ...
```

Component:

```
// resp is an array received from axios.get:

this.$store.commit({
     type: 'setCases',
     items: resp
})
```

resp is an object array. When Vuex calls the setCases() mutation, only the first object of the array is delivered in 'items'.

Why is that?

Comment: Looking at this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html [see Object-Style Commit section]


```
When using object-style commit, the entire object will be passed as the payload to mutation handlers, so the handler remains the same
```

The `resp` value should be accessible as `items.items` in the mutation function, right? Could you verify this is actually the case?

Comment: Great @gvk, thanks a lot, you saved my day!

Comment: Cool. Added as an answer in case someone else stumbles upon this without fully RTFM-ing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html [see Object-Style Commit section]

> When using object-style commit, the entire object will be passed as
>   the payload to mutation handlers, so the handler remains the same

The `resp` value should be accessible as `items.items` in the mutation function.