# Axios API Call failing to save full array response into variable

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I am using Axios to do get data from an API and save this data into an empty variable. However, I am not able to save the entire API call to the variable.

```
export default createStore({
  state: {
    apiUrl: "http://localhost:8090/", 
    monthlyData: [],
    
  },
  mutations: {
    setMonthlyData(state, newValue){
      state.monthlyData = newValue
    },
  },
actions: {
  getData({ commit, dispatch, state }) {
  console.log("Fetching  monthly data from the backend...");
      axios.get(state.apiUrl + "/monthly/4")
        .then(response => {
          commit('setMonthlyData', response.data)
            console.log(response.status);
            console.log(response.data);
            console.log(response.data.length);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        })
    
      }
```

This is the result of the API Call and that I want to save in a variable

```
[{"date":"2021-01-16","month":"Jan","name":"User Negative Hour 6","projects":["63213","53213","83213","73213","213213","53212"],"quarter":"Q1","year":"2021"},{"date":"2021-02-16","month":"Feb","name":"User Negative Hour 6","projects":["213213","63213","53212","73213","53213","83213"],"quarter":"Q1","year":"2021"},{"date":"2021-03-16","month":"Mar","name":"User Negative Hour 6","projects":["53212","63213","213213","83213","73213","53213"],"quarter":"Q1","year":"2021"}]
```

But the value is not stored in the monthlyData variable. However, if I do

```
commit('setMonthlyData', response.data[0])
```

This will work, and I will get the first element of the array from the API. But it is not what I want(All the array and not a given element).

```
{"date":"2021-01-16","month":"Jan","name":"User Negative Hour 6","projects":["63213","53213","83213","73213","213213","53212"],"quarter":"Q1","year":"2021"}
```

The response.status is 200, response.data.length is 3 as it should be.

I am struggling to find out what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did You try to spread data `state.monthlyData = [...newValue]`

Comment: I just tried it, but it did not work

Comment: Please checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107449/committing-array-to-vuex-store-mutation

Comment: Thanks for the link, finally I understood how to apply it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout this answer: [Committing array to Vuex store mutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58107449/committing-array-to-vuex-store-mutation)

Maybe you can try

```
  mutations: {
    setMonthlyData(state, newValue){
      Vue.set(state, 'monthlyData', newValue)
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

In the store/index.js file I updated the setMonthlyData function with .items

```
setMonthlyData(state, newValue){
        state.monthlyData.items = newValue
```

```
axios.get(state.apiUrl + "monthly/4")
        .then(response => {
          commit('setMonthlyData', response.data)
```

and in a view I called it as follow:

```
this.$store.getters.monthlyBillability.items
```